# MySQLi prepared query in while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have already preapred query above while loop, and I want to when I get data from already preapred, to use it in query in while loop, but I get this error: **Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ----**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $query = $mysqli_conn->prepare("SELECT id,cvjecara_u,stock_id,kolicina,novca,datum FROM narucio ORDER BY id DESC");
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($db_id,$db_cvjecara_u,$db_stock_id,$db_kolicina,$db_novca,$db_datum);

        while($query->fetch()){
            $c_id = $db_stock_id;
            $queryy = $mysqli_conn->prepare("SELECT naziv,kolicina2 FROM stock WHERE id = ?");
            $queryy->bind_param('i',$c_id);
            $queryy->execute();
            $queryy->bind_result($db_naziv,$db_kolicina2);
            $queryy->fetch();

            echo $db_cvjecara_u.$db_naziv.$db_kolicina.$db_kolicina2.$db_novca.$db_datum;
            $queryy->close();
        }
        $query->close();

        ?>
```

Comment: Why didn't you just use [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)?

Comment: I dont know, I will try